# separte rows in php from csv

Tags: php, csv

I do have a phone list with five columns of name, age, type, address, phone & mail and around 50 rows of data. The data is in csv format (file: my_data.csv).

```
NAME   AGE  TYPE    ADDRESS                           PHONE    Email
Robert 36  Freind CA Avenue, jercy street, Machigon   3456231  robert_78@gmail.com
Calux  24  Lover  new opera, bank steet,Machigaon     3456760  calux899@yahoo.com
Gandy  25  Lover  Ninth house, dark square, machigaon 3458923  gandy_12@gmail.com
```

For my project, I am linking the csv with php and my php file is: get-add.php.
The source code is given below:

```
<?php
$check="Lover"; // to be checked in the third column
  $handle = fopen("my_data.csv","r")or die("file dont exist");
  $output = '';
   while (!feof($handle )){
    $data = fgetcsv($handle,2096,",");
        if(($data[2] ==$check)){
           $output .= sprintf( "%s; Age: %d; %s; %s; Ph:%d; Mail: %s )<br>", 
           $data[0], $data[1], $data[2], $data[3], $data[4], $data[5]);
        }
    }
echo $output;
fclose($handle);
?>
```

and the results comes in folowing format.

```
Calux; Age:24; Type:Lover  new opera, bank steet,Machigaon; Ph:3456760; Mail:calux899@yahoo.com
Gandy  Age:25; Type:Lover;  Ninth house, dark square, machigaon; Ph:3458923; Mail:gandy_12@gmail.com
```

Whereas I need in the following format.

```
Calux   Age:24;   Lover  
        new opera, bank steet,Machigaon  
        Ph:3456760  
        Mail: calux899@yahoo.com

Gandy   Age:25;  Lover  
        Ninth house, dark square, machigaon 
        Ph:3458923 
        Mail: gandy_12@gmail.com
```

Please helpme friends in correcting the php code.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you're outputting to. If it's a terminal screen or text file, add `\n` where you need it, if it's a browser, it's `<br />`. Of course, if you're outputting to a browser, you might want to use HTML to format it anyway.

And for tabs, it's `\t`, but not for HTML. That goes back to formatting.